# OpenGL and Images/Sprites

Tags: opengl, sfml

If I wanted to display a sprite and/or texture to my SFML window, and have it move when keys are pressed, would I be better off using OpenGL to draw the sprite to the screen(If even possible, I only just started looking into this) or would it be better to use SFML for it?

Comment: SFML sprites weren't exactly top quality when I've tried to use them last time, bit since you have to ask...

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard question to answer, because it depends on various things.

### What is OpenGL & SFML ?

#### OpenGL

OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) is a huge and advanced cross-platform API for rendering 2D and 3D graphics. The API mainly tries to focus on using the GPU to achieve hardware-accelerated rendering.

#### SFML

SFML (Simple and Fast Multimedia Library) is a portable and easy-to-use API for 2D rendering. The API runs on top of OpenGL, therefore SFML is also hardware accelerated.

**Edit:** SFML is a multimedia, portable and easy-to-use API, for various things. The API is composed of 5 different modules for controling – System, Window, Graphics, Audio and Network.

### OpenGL or SFML

First you need to ask yourself some questions.

- How experienced am I?
- Have I worked with any of them before?
- etc...

If you've worked with any of these two APIs, you can simply choose to use the one you already know. Because appending you knowledge to the library you already know, is usually a lot easier than learning something entirely new.

If you don't know OpenGL or SFML, then the choice can be a bit harder, but keep the following in mind.

#### OpenGL

- It requires a lot of learning!
- You need to handle/create/use/know about a lot of different stuff, to simply use it.
- You need to know about [Matrix Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) as well as [Euclidean Vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) and even more, to simply making a basic program work.

#### SFML

- As stated in the name ***Simple*** and Fast Multimedia Library, it's meant to be simple!
- SFML handles a lot of things for you, which you need to do yourself while using OpenGL.
- You don't **need** to know about [Matrix Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29) as well as [Euclidean Vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) just to make a basic program.

### Conclusion

- If you know about any of them, use the one you know the most about!
- If you don't know any of them yet, and want something simple, start with SMFL.
- If you want something advanced and learn a lot of new things and be in control of how every little thing is handled go for OpenGL.

When you first know OpenGL, it's really easy. Though the process of knowing nothing to know most or all of the things within OpenGL is hard and takes time!

So if you want to start with something simple use SFML because loading Textures and using then is a lot easier than with pure OpenGL, because in OpenGL you need to make your own Texture classes which handles loading and creation of textures. Where in SFML there is already a texture class as well as way of loading them, etc.

### Sprites & Textures

- [SFML - Sprites and Textures](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-sprite.php)
- [OpenGL - Loading and using Textures](http://open.gl/textures)

Comment: SFML is not only an API, because it comes with an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically SFML uses OpenGL, SFML is just an easier way to access some of the functions OpenGL implements